# Prove that union of two equivalences relations is also equivalence relation if and only if that union equals to thier compositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let *R$_1$*, *$R_2$* be two equivalence relations on *X*. Prove that *R$_1$* $\bigcup$ *R$_2$* is an equivalence relation if and only if *R$_1$* $\bigcup$ *R$_2$* = *R$_1$* $\circ$ *R$_2$*.

Comment: What have you done to try and solve the problem so far?

Comment: I know how to prove that R1∪R2 is reflexive and symmetric. I have a problem with proving transitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. We always have $R_1\cup R_2\subseteq R_1\circ R_2$.

   > $R_1=R_1\circ\mathrm{Id} \subseteq R_1\circ R_2$, similarly $R_2\subseteq R_1\circ R_2$.
2. Any equivalence relation that contains $R_1\cup R_2\,$ must contain $R_1\circ R_2$ as well.

   > Because of transitivity: suppose $R_1\cup R_2\subseteq E$, and let $a\, R_1\circ R_2\, c$, then there's a $b$ in between, and $a\, E\, b\, E\, c$ hence $a\, E\, c$ holds.
3. If $R_1\cup R_2=R_1\circ R_2$ then also $R_2\circ R_1=(R_1\circ R_2)^{op}=R_1\cup R_2$. 
   You can apply it to show that $R_1\cup R_2$ is transitive.

   > $R_1\circ R_2\circ R_1\circ R_2\ =\ R_1\circ R_1\circ R_2\circ R_2\ \subseteq\ R_1\circ R_2$.

Comment: "Any equivalence relation that contains R1∪R2 must contain R1∘R2 as well."
Why?

Comment: And why "We always have R1∪R2⊆R1∘R2"? I understand the third one, but I can't understand why 1. and 2. is true.

Comment: I updated my answer. The important thing is that relation composition is *monotonic*: preserves $\subseteq$ of relations.